# network stream analysis using wireshark and apache storm

Tags: json, networking, apache-storm, wireshark

I want to make a simple application that analyzes network traffic generated by **Wireshark** and counts how often I access google. From this project I want to introduce myself to network traffic processing.

In order to get traffic, I use Wireshark.
In order to analyze the network traffic streams I want to use **Apache Storm.**

Well, I am new to stream processing, apache storm and wireshark (this is very first use), so I want to ask you if is possible to realize this simple project.

I think Apache Storm can read the data easily from json files.

So the things that puzzles me are:

- Can I export wireshark data to json files?
- Can I, somehow read in real time the data generated from wireshark,
- Process this data using Apache Storm,
- Or, if you can suggest me a more appropriate instrument with a concrete tutorial I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting project to start with.

1. To read data from Wireshark in real-time, I suppose you can make use of any [Wireshark API](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/29624/java-api-to-dissect-wireless-packets-captured-by-wireshark-libcap) and then create a client that pushes data to some port in your system.
2. Create a **Storm Spout** that reads from this port
3. Create a **Storm Bolt** to parse these message (if you want to convert to json)
4. Create a **Storm Bolt** to filter the traffic (the ones between google? may be based on IP address?)
5. Optionally store the results to some datastore.

Alternatives : You can also try [apache-flink](/questions/tagged/apache-flink) or [apache-spark](/questions/tagged/apache-spark), which also provides stream processing capabilities.